# Not able to log in to Area 51

Tags: support, area-51, login

Tried on Safari and Chrome, getting same issue.
I can login to other sites like SO and this one.

[image: A screenshot: “Unable to log in: No user found”]

Tried on a different machine and still having same issue.

Comment: Have you tried to sign up? I don't see an Area 51 credential on your account.

Comment: oh that works. thanks. shouldn't it create an account for me automatically? I visited area 51 long time ago and wasn't aware that I don't have an account for it.

Comment: Area 51 is a ... bit special. On most sites, there's an easy way to add a profile but Area 51 is on an old code base that doesn't have that. It won't even have the same avatar if you have an uploaded one, which you don't... but if you find my account there, you'll see it's got a gravatar instead of my imgur avatar. Glad that worked for you. :D

Comment: make sense. my suggestion will be at least change the error message to say something like please signup first.

Comment: I'm... not sure if that's possible but it would be good to have it say something like "No user found, if you have a Stack Exchange account, please try the "sign up" option." ... maybe? I'll see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't actually have an account created there, which is why you can't log in. You need to use the "sign up" option, instead.

Area 51 is on an older version of our code base, which means you have to actually sign up rather than being able to just activate a profile on the site. It should recognize your credentials, so your accounts are connected properly.

Apologies for the confusion!